# Use help2man in parallel automake

Tags: automake

I'm working on a project built using GNU autotools (autoconf, automake). It does work well, but I've a problem with help2man: When building parallel (`MAKEFLAGS=-j3`), the project is built twice - once using "normal" target, once using the `foo.1` make call.

The following is the relevant part from `Makefile.am`:

```
foo.1 : $(top_srcdir)/man/foo.x $(top_srcdir)/src/main.c $(top_srcdir)/configure.ac
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) foo$(EXEEXT)
    -$(HELP2MAN) -o $@ --include $< $(top_builddir)/foo
```

So, my question is how to write `Makefile.am` to support the following:

1. Distribute `foo.1` to support systems without `help2man`
2. Do not throw errors
3. Rebuild manpage if necessary

I'm looking forward to your answer

Comment: Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no easy solution to this question; the following works for me.

In `configure.ac`, you have to check for help2man. If cross-compiling, you must not run help2man, as the executable will be run. The following snippet is therefore contained:

```
# Man pages
AS_IF([test "$cross_compiling" = "no"], [
    AM_MISSING_PROG([HELP2MAN], [help2man])
], [
    HELP2MAN=:
])
```

For building, there is a two-level concept. First, you check if the manpage is newer than the executable; if so, to prohibit unnecessary manpage rebuilds, you check against the source using a temporary file being last altered when the manpage itself was. So, `Makefile.am` contains:

```
dist_man_MANS = foo.1
EXTRA_DIST += $(dist_man_MANS:.1=.x) common.x
MOSTLYCLEANFILES += $(dist_man_MANS:=-t)
MAINTAINERCLEANFILES += $(dist_man_MANS)

common_dep = $(top_srcdir)/common.x $(top_srcdir)/configure.ac $(top_srcdir)/.version
common_indirect_dep = $(top_srcdir)/common.x $(top_srcdir)/configure $(top_srcdir)/.version
foo.1 : $(common_indirect_dep) $(top_builddir)/foo$(EXEEXT)
foo.1-t : $(common_dep) $(top_srcdir)/main-helpversion.c

SUFFIXES += .x .1 .1-t
.x.1:
    test -f $@ || if test -f $(top_srcdir)/`echo $@ | $(SED) -e 's,.*/,,'`; then \
        touch -r $(top_srcdir)/`echo $@ | $(SED) -e 's,.*/,,'` $@; \
    else \
        touch -d @0 $@; \
    fi
    touch -r $@ $@-t
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $@-t
    if test -s $@-t; then \
        mv -f $@-t $@; \
    else \
        rm -f $@-t; \
        if test -s $@; then touch $@; else rm -f $@; fi; \
    fi
.x.1-t:
    $(HELP2MAN) -o $@ -I $< -I $(top_srcdir)/common.x -s 1 foo$(EXEEXT)
```

Comment: One of those drawbacks is that `make -j3` reintroduces the build race of `foo$(EXEEXT)` that you said you were trying to avoid originally...

Comment: Are you sure about that? I think, my (GNU) make resolves this. Imagine targets A and B are built parallel, while B depends on A (which is the above example simplified); as far as I can see, make resolves this correctly

Comment: Using GNU make 4.0.  You've reintroduced the recursive make of your original example (with some more protection).  In a clean state, that protection doesn't exist and I get two invocations to build `foo$(EXEXT)`.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.1` needs correct prerequisites.  AIUI, `help2man` just needs the executable binary to be built:

```
foo.1 : $(top_srcdir)/man/foo.x $(top_srcdir)/configure.ac $(top_builddir)/foo
        -$(HELP2MAN) -o $@ --include $< $(top_builddir)/foo
```

so that's 3)

don't understand what you want out of 2), which is not possible in general.

```
dist_man_MANS = foo.1
```

which is 1)

Comment: I already tried this idea, but the end user needs to have help2man installed cuz the manpage is rebuild even if sources don't change

Comment: The user need not have `help2man` installed, if it's searched for using [AC_CHECK_PROG](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/autoconf.html#Generic-Programs), The AC_CHECK_PROG test can also be used to exclude the `foo.1` rule above via a [conditional](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Usage-of-Conditionals.html) when `help2man` is not installed.

Comment: However, make distcheck faiks anyway, as the manpage is rebuild at the end-user (if possible), but not only if necessary. See https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Errors-with-distclean.html

Comment: Adding `CLEANFILES += $(dist_man_MANS)` makes `make distcheck` (which would be in the same conditional as the `foo.1` rule) pass for me using this method.  You might want to look at [GNU Hello](https://www.gnu.org/software/hello/) (specifically hello-2.10) which uses a variation of this method.  They also test for cross-compilation during `configure` (`help2man` would fail during cross-compilation).

Comment: Yes, the hello solution works. Though it rebulds too often too. I think I've found another solution, I'll post later